# AWS SDK: manually install thrid-party tools

Tags: aws-sdk-cpp

**Issue** Error while build AWD SDK (C++) library.

I am  trying to build the AWD SDK packages, and getting errors.
It seems that something is wrong with the 'automatically download' of third party tools, and the install procedure gets stalled. (maybe my IT department is blocking a port!)

This is what I'm using:

- git: v1.9.9
- cmake: v3.8.2
- curl: v3.8.2
- gcc: v6.3

Here is the output log:

```
-- Found Git: /grid/common/pkgs/git/latest/bin/git (found version "1.9.0") 
-- TARGET_ARCH not specified; inferring host OS to be platform compilation target
-- Building AWS libraries as shared objects
-- Generating linux build config
fatal: Not a git repository: '/home/dargollo/aws/aws-sdk-cpp-master/.git'
-- Building project version: 1.7.42
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /grid/common/pkgs/gcc/v6.3.0/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /grid/common/pkgs/gcc/v6.3.0/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /grid/common/pkgs/gcc/v6.3.0/bin/g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /grid/common/pkgs/gcc/v6.3.0/bin/g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/dargollo/aws/blddir/.deps
Scanning dependencies of target AwsCCommon
[  4%] Creating directories for 'AwsCCommon'
[  8%] Performing download step (git clone) for 'AwsCCommon'
Cloning into 'AwsCCommon'...
Cloning into 'AwsCCommon'...
Cloning into 'AwsCCommon'...
-- Had to git clone more than once:
          3 times.
```

**Question**
Is it possible to bypass the automatically git download? I can download the packages individually, and copy then somewhere....

- aws-c-common-master.zip
- aws-c-event-stream-master.zip
- aws-checksums-master.zip

Comment: Looks like it might be failing because you downloaded the project via github instead of using git clone? The package name of `aws-sdk-cpp-master` tells me this

Comment: You're following?: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-cpp/v1/developer-guide/setup.html

Comment: yes - I am following the setup guide: In the section "To build the SDK from source" it allows the download of the zip file without clone.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to old versions of curl, and git installed on my system. 
Hit was getting sucked and not able to download. I did not find a way to build/install the AWS/SDK without using git for the 3rd party tools.

After I downloaded and built those packages, the aws sdk installation performed fine without any problem.

I have used:

```
curl from: https://github.com/curl/curl/tree/curl-7_63_0
git from https://github.com/git/git
```

with versions:

```
curl 7.63.0-DEV (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.63.0-DEV OpenSSL/1.0.1e 
git version 2.20.GIT
```